# Maintain cell reference when substituting new sheet

Tags: excel, reference, spreadsheet

I am performing a portfolio calculation based upon a daily spreadsheet which contains values in the same cell locations.

I would like to be able to substitute daily a new sheet via the copy function, yet maintain the cell reference.

EG, I have a 'control' sheet which references cells D4, E4 and F4 in sheet B.  Every day a new Sheet B is published with the relevant values in the same cells.  Is there a way I can maintain the references in the Control sheet when inserting this new sheet daily?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on how the new sheets are named, you can probably use the `INDIRECT()` function.

If the newly-published sheet will be the same name every time, then to refer to B3 on that sheet use:

```
=INDIRECT("SheetName!B3", TRUE)
```

If the name changes predictably, in this example if each day's sheet is named after that day's date, use a formula within the `INDIRECT` function to adapt the sheet name as required, like so:

```
=INDIRECT(TEXT(TODAY(), "dd.mm.yy") & "!B3")
```

(where `TEXT(TODAY(), "dd.mm.yy")` is the sheet name)

Comment: If the sheet name isn't predictable every day, you could still do it if you were willing to type the sheet name in a cell somewhere and then reference that cell within the INDIRECT formulas.

Comment: This isn't working...I am getting a #REF! Error message.  Usually, when I refer to a different tab, the tab name is enclosed in single quotes.   The suggestion above does not generate these quotes.  Is this the source of the error?

Comment: Update:  It appears as if INDIRECT does not work if there is a space in the name of the tab.   Otherwise, works a treat. 
Thanks!

Comment: @GPB Add a single quote either side of the sheet name, within the double-quotes as follows: `=INDIRECT("'Sheet Name'!B3")` and then it should be fine.